# Looking for ideas of starting web developing

Tags: content-management-system

I want to start designing/developing web sites,

I started learning HTML and CSS, and came up with this Content Management Systems which are used mostly by web developers.

So, now I am a bit confused of what to learn, 
So my questions are,
1. Should I continue learning HTML and CSS only?
2. Should I stop learning HTML and CSS and continue with CMS?
3. Should I do both parallel?

Kindly help me with this,

Thank you.

Comment: This question is irrelevant to programming.

Comment: I am actually a starter to web developing, kinda not know in which path I should select to proceed,
And this is related to CMS